# How can I continue to the next iteration when a certain iteration takes too much time in python?

Tags: python, loops, timer

I'm reading emails with a for loop.
It looks something like:

```py
for mail in mail_list:
    # When it takes more than 30 secs, call handle_timeout function
    timer = threading.Timer(30, handle_timeout)
    timer.start()
    self.read_single_mail(mail)
    timer.cancel()
```

When implementing `handle_timeout` function, how can I do `continue` operation for the loop?

Or if there is another good way to achieve this other than `timer`, please let me know.

**=====EDITED=====**

I tried with some more code,

```py
def handle_timeout:
    raise TimeoutError

for mail in mail_list:
    # When it takes more than 30 secs, call handle_timeout function
    try:
        timer = threading.Timer(30, handle_timeout)
        timer.start()
        self.read_single_mail(mail)
        timer.cancel()
    except TimeoutError:
        continue
```

But this also fails.

I expected that after 30 secs TimeoutError will be raised, and it will execute the `continue` operation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490555/python-timeout-decorator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)